# Failed to instantiate firebase module

Tags: angularjs, firebase, npm

I've recently installed firebase via npm but when i try to import it and set it as a dependency to my app module I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app-bootstrap due to:
>   Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module firebase due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'firebase' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

I'm using import "firebase" in my main.js file. Every other import works except for firebase.

What could be the issue ?

main.js :

```
import 'angular';
import 'angular-ui-router';
import 'angular-animate';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'angularfire';

// Libs wrapper

import 'assets/css/main.scss'

// Module wrapper
import 'modules';

let config = {
     apiKey: "",
     authDomain: "",
     databaseURL: "",
     projectId: "",
     storageBucket: "",
}
     firebase.initializeApp(config);

angular
  .module('app-bootstrap', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngAnimate',
    'firebase',
    'modules'
  ])


angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['app-bootstrap']);
});
```

Random controller:

```
export function authCtrl($firebaseAuth) {
    let vm = this;
    vm.authObj = $firebaseAuth();


}
```

Later edit:

I managed to solve the Uncaught Error and now I get a different error "ReferenceError: firebase is not defined"

Comment: AngularFire (or AngularFire2) are built to help work with Firebase in Angular applications.  The steps in the documentation (https://github.com/firebase/angularfire or https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) should help get you going.  You can also follow the instructions to run a local copy for development.

Comment: Did read the documentation before attempting to install. I also have angularfire installed via npm but as I said in the beggining, it gives me that error.

Comment: I've edited my initial post. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You likely want to mask the key etc.. so people do not abuse your firebase account limits.

Answer (score 0):

In my environment I just use AngularFire2, and not Firebase directly.

```
...
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
...
@NgModule({
...
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(Configuration.Firebase),
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        AngularFireDatabaseModule
    ],
```

...
    })
    export class AppModule {}

Then, in classes needing the AngularFire2 access, you pass it as a dependency on the constructor:

```
export class SomeClass {
    DataForPage: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, FirebaseData: AngularFireDatabase ) {
    this.DataForPage = FirebaseData.list('/data');
}
...
```

Or

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, FirebaseData: AngularFireDatabase, Auth:AngularFireAuthModule ) {
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer, tho I'm not familiar with Angular2.

Comment: Sorry, thought you were using Angular2 with the let keyword and imports being in typescript.  Can you not remove the initialize from firebase and use AngularFire for that, then still provide the service as a dependency to your controllers?

Comment: Hm, in the angularfire documentation it says that I need to initialize with firebase. How would I go about doing what you said ?

Comment: Not sure as I use Angular2 and have not used the new firebase with older Angular apps.